# Dependency Injection into a AuthorizationFilterAttribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, unity-container

I am pretty new to Unity & IoC in general & as usual, I have quickly got myself into a bind...

I have created an Authorization Filter Attribute for the ASP.NET Web API Beta. I now need to inject my Authorizer into the Attribute however since this is an attribute I cannot simply do this `public TestAuthAttribute(IAuthorizer Authorizer)` in my constructor.

So I then decided to create a public property decorated with the [Dependency] attribute for property injection however it does not get resolved.

Here is the code:

```
public class TestAuthAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    [Dependency]
    public IAuthorizer Authorizer { get; set; }

    public TestAuthAttribute() {
        ...
        }

    private bool authorizeCore(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        if (Authorizer == null)
            throw Error.ArgumentNull("Null Authorizer");  // <<<<< this is null
    }
```

When the controller is decorated with the [TestAuth] the Attribute is triggered but the Authorizer is not resolved, it is null)

I have placed the following code in my controller & Authorizer does get resolved...

```
[Dependency]
    public IAuthorizer Authorizer { get; set; }
```

Why is this dependency not resolved in my AuthorizationFilterAttribute & how would you go about Injecting the Authorizer into the AuthorizationFilterAttribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full disclosure: I have not used Turbine.

Having said that, I think it might solve your problem for you or at least show you how to solve it.

They have a Unity Nuget package here: http://nuget.org/packages/MvcTurbine.Unity

And you can find more detail on their codeplex site here: http://mvcturbine.codeplex.com/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, being pretty new to IoC, I am inferring from the link that MVC is instantiating the FilterAttribute therefore the dependency injection is never occurring. Is this basically what is happening?

Comment: @TimBhd Right.  Unless you wire it up to your container explicitly, MVC doesn't know you are trying to use Unity.  See also this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035611/mvc-unity-how-to-inject-dependencies-into-custom-filterattributes.  I think that is a more direct solution if you don't want to take a dependency on Turbine.

Comment: @TimBhd See also Jimmy Bogard's post: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/05/03/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-filters/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%253A+LosTechies+%2528LosTechies%2529.

Comment: Thanks for the info & links. That last one was a new one to me & shed some light. I went back and gave it another go using a custom Filter Attribute Provider like the one here: [link](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt4-filters.html). The solution works great for typical MVC but for the Beta ASP.net Web API the provider never fires. I'm guessing I need to find some corresponding filter attribute provider in the Web API.

Comment: @TimBhd That's likely an issue with Beta that will be resolved in the upcoming RC.  I do not believe they are supposed to behave differently post-merge with MVC. I'd suggest posting your issue (linking this post, actually) on the Web API forums.  The community (including Microsoft) are very active and you'll get better visibility on this type of issue there. The forum is here: http://forums.asp.net/1246.aspx/1?ASP+NET+Web+API. Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

I use Ninject for similar purpose. I do have a reference to Ninject.Web.WebAPI which works perfectly.

However, this does not seem working with MVC4 RC.